# Stop all the code and continue afterwards, like an alert() in JS

Tags: javascript, alert

Let me explain: When you call an alert() in JS, all the code that in below of the alert, will stop and when you click in Ok, the code returns work.

I make my own Custom Alert with this code:

```
function cAlert()
{
var bOn;
this.show = function (content)
{       
    bOn = true;
    document.write('<div id="turnOffLight"></div><div id="cAlertBox"><div id="cAlertImageBox"><img style="position: absolute; top: 54%; left: 50%; margin-top: -32px; margin-left: -32px;" src="Images/Vectors/1429744831_678136-shield-warning-64.png" alt=""/> </div><div id="cAlertContentBox"> </div><div id="cAlertButtonBox"><input id="cAlertButtonStyle" type="button" value="OK" onclick="cAlert.ok()" /></div></div>');
    $("#cAlertContentBox").html(content);
    $("#cAlertBox").show();
    $("#turnOffLight").fadeIn("fast");

    var div = document.getElementById('cAlertBox').offsetWidth;
    var res = -Math.abs(div / 2);
    document.getElementById('cAlertBox').style.marginTop = res + "px";
};
this.ok = function ()
{
    $("#cAlertBox").hide();
    $("#turnOffLight").fadeOut("medium");
    bOn = false;
};
}
```

and in the other pages:

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jQuery_1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/cAlertScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var cAlert = new cAlert();</script>
</head>
```

but I have a problem, in login page, after call the cAlert(), I call this:

```
echo "<script>javascript:history.go(-1)</script>";
```

to return to the last page, when I used to using the alert(), only after the user click in ok, the browser return to the last page, but using the cAlert, the browser already returns to the last page.

What I want is that the user need to click in Ok button to the code continue as an alert().

Comment: This is just impossible in JS besides for the native functions `alert()`, `confirm()`, and `prompt()`. Only those have the ability to stop the execution thread. Unless of course you feel like writing your own JavaScript engine that would stop execution on some other function as well... :P +1 for well-written question anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Change `cAlert.show(content)` to `cAlert.show(content, success)`.
Change `cAlert.ok()` to `cAlert.ok(' + success + ')`.
Change `this.ok = function ()` to `this.ok = function (success)`, and finally add `success();` to the end of the `ok()` function.

This will call `success` when the button in the cAlert is clicked.

Instead of calling `cAlert.show("text")` you now need to call `cAlert.show("text", function() { javascript:history.go(-1); } )`.

---

So your code should now be:

```
function cAlert()
{
var bOn;
this.show = function (content, success)
{       
    bOn = true;
    document.write('<div id="turnOffLight"></div><div id="cAlertBox"><div id="cAlertImageBox"><img style="position: absolute; top: 54%; left: 50%; margin-top: -32px; margin-left: -32px;" src="Images/Vectors/1429744831_678136-shield-warning-64.png" alt=""/> </div><div id="cAlertContentBox"> </div><div id="cAlertButtonBox"><input id="cAlertButtonStyle" type="button" value="OK" onclick="cAlert.ok(' + success + ')" /></div></div>');
    $("#cAlertContentBox").html(content);
    $("#cAlertBox").show();
    $("#turnOffLight").fadeIn("fast");

    var div = document.getElementById('cAlertBox').offsetWidth;
    var res = -Math.abs(div / 2);
    document.getElementById('cAlertBox').style.marginTop = res + "px";
};
this.ok = function (success)
{
    $("#cAlertBox").hide();
    $("#turnOffLight").fadeOut("medium");
    bOn = false;

    success();
};
}
```

and:

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jQuery_1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/cAlertScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cAlert = new cAlert();
        cAlert.show("text", function() { javascript:history.go(-1); } );
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I use this: 
echo "<script>cAlert.show('Logado com sucesso!', function() { javascript:history.go(-1);});</script>";
The alert appears, but when I click in Ok, nothing happens.

Comment: lol i forgot te edit half of the code, and later figured out it didn't work in the first place. It should work now though, i've tested it... So check the edited post and hope i didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the page to go back once the OK button is clicked, place the function call or code to go back in the `cAlert.ok()` function. This way the page will only go back once the user has clicked the OK button since this function only gets called when the user clicks the OK button.

```
this.ok = function ()
{
    $("#cAlertBox").hide();
    $("#turnOffLight").fadeOut("medium");
    bOn = false;

    window.history.go(-1);
};
```

Comment: This won't serve to me because I want to use this alert in other pages, and not aways, I need to return to the last page...